# Creating a view with a function inside

Tags: mysql, wamp

I am trying to create a view with a function inside.
When I want to look at the created view I get an error message

> ## 1318 - Incorrect number of arguments for function ret_stat; expected 1, got 0

This is my function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION ret_stat (ret_stat CHAR (50))
RETURNS CHAR DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE result CHAR;
SET result = "";
SET result =
    CASE (result)
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) > 5 THEN '5 plus years'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) > 4 THEN '5 years left'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) > 3 THEN '4 years left'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) > 2 THEN '3 years left'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) > 1 THEN '2 years left'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) = 1 THEN '1 year left'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) = 0 THEN 'Soon retirement'
         WHEN (65-(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(bdate))) < 0 THEN 'Retired'
         END;
RETURN result;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

...and this is my query for my view:

```
 CREATE VIEW ret_stat_view AS
 SELECT fname, lname, faculty, ret_stat()
 FROM employees;
```

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: When I want to look at the created view I get the error msg that is mentioned above.
I don't understand why.

Comment: SQL functions in MySQL don't have a optional input i wished you could define `CREATE FUNCTION ret_stat (ret_stat CHAR (50) DEFUALT ....)` .. Also you never seam to use in the input param off the function? And what is `bdate` in the function?

Comment: @RaymondNijland
Yes, being a total beginner I am trying to learn how it works. That is why I am here, to learn from the experts.

Yes, I realised that I am not using the ret_stat char.
bdate is a column in my employees table.

Comment: I looked around stackoverflow to find an answer, but I am very unsure about functions. It is a weakness of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function's parameter needs to be the bdate as a date, and the return value is TEXT, result is TEXT too, the CASE doesn't need any parameter.
... and it works as it should!

KAPOW downvoters!
★★★★★

> Veni, vidi, solvī!

Comment: *"and it works as it should!"* i doubt that see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7aCPwjyBUWSiehzVFaA2nx/0) , like i said before i already i doubted the calulation was correct.